# ¿Por qué se me antepone primero el scanner antes de mi pregunta con el comando System.out.print("")?

Tags: java

¿porqué se salta mi pregunta elaborada con el comando System.out y lee primero el scanner.

```
public class NewMain1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//Se crea un objeto Scanner 
        String nombre;
        double radio;
        int n;
        System.out.print("Introduzca su nombre: ");

        nombre = sc.nextLine();  //leer un String

        System.out.println("Hola " + nombre + "!!!");
        System.out.print("Introduzca el radio de la circunferencia: ");
        radio = sc.nextDouble(); //leer un double

        System.out.println("Longitud de la circunferencia: " + 2 * Math.PI * radio);
        System.out.print("Introduzca un número entero: ");
        n = sc.nextInt(); //leer un entero

        System.out.println("El cuadrado es: " + Math.pow(n, 2));
    }
}

introducir el código aquí
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque está programado así. String nombre = sc.nextline() se quedará esperando hasta que teclees algo y pulses intro. Por cortesía, todo lo que se teclea por el usuario sale por pantalla (es una funcionalidad que se llama echo). Por lo tanto lo primero que hace tu programa es esperar a que escribas algo y pulses intro. Y además, ya que echo está activo, todo lo que escribas se verá por pantalla.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: cambia las imágenes por código; luego seleccionalo y usa CTR+k para que stackoverflow le ponga el highligh de código.

Comment: Hola, @RaulLuna. He escrito primero String nombre y luego el scanner pero me sigue saliendo igual primero me pide ingresar datos y luego me imprime la pregunta .¿Entonces que desactivar la funcion echo? .Igual muchas gracias por comentar

Comment: A ver: que tu programa no funciona mal. Lo que funciona mal es el entorno de desarrollo. Ejecutalo en una ventana de comandos y verás que te funciona correctamente. Mi consejo es que no te obsesiones con que te funcione bien en Netbeans o el entorno de desarrollo que estés usando, ya que se trata solo de eso: el sitio donde desarrollas. La aplicación se ejecutará en una ventana de comandos, y ahí, que yo sepa, va a funcionar correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

*Bueno una forma de solucionar el problema que he encontrado es poniendo a todo System.out.println() y la otra manera seria poniendo "\n" al mensaje de System.out.println*

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//Se crea un objeto Scanner 
    String nombre;
    double radio;
    int n;
    System.out.print( " Introduzca su nombre: \n");
    nombre = sc.nextLine();  //leer un String
    System.out.println(" Hola " + nombre + "!!!");
    System.out.print("Introduzca el radio de la circunferencia: \n ");
    radio = sc.nextDouble(); //leer un double
    System.out.println("Longitud de la circunferencia: " + 2 * Math.PI * radio);
    System.out.print("Introduzca un número entero: \n ");
    n = sc.nextInt(); //leer un entero
    System.out.println("El cuadrado es: " + Math.pow(n, 2));
}
```

Este es el resultado que me dio aunque esperaba con el comando que yo indico osea con el comando System.out.print("")
*Ingrese nombre: Diego* ->Asi esperaba que me saliera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es un defecto del entorno de desarrollo que estás usando.

Si ejecutas esto desde la ventana de comandos, funciona correctamente. Desde eclipse, que lo he probado, también funciona correctamente. Este es el comportamiento que se observa desde eclipse:

```
Introduzca su nombre: Diego
Hola Diego!!!
Introduzca el radio de la circunferencia: 20
Longitud de la circunferencia: 125.66370614359172
Introduzca un número entero: 40
El cuadrado es: 1600.0
```

Como solución, ejecuta siempre este programa desde una ventana de comandos. Y si decides ejecutarlo desde el entorno de desarrollo, ten en cuenta que el orden en que te aparecerán las entradas y salidas no es el correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Tenia el mismo problema y mi error era que al crear el proyecto en el IDE de NetBeans lo hacia con `Java with Maven`.

[image: Java maven]

Entonces tenia ese 'error' que no le encontraba solución, al final probando me di cuenta que había que hacerlo con `Java with Ant`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No te sabria dar una explicación a esto, he estado buscando y no me han quedado muy clara las diferencias entre ambas, lo que si se, es que para solucionar eso, tienes que crear el  proyecto con `Java with Ant`.

Adjunto pruebas de ello:

codigo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Nombre: ");
    String nombre = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hola "+nombre);
}
```

}

Salida en Maven:

[image: Salida en Maven]

Salida en Ant:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]